# Some SPARQL commands don't work when used in ISQL

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have installed a local virtuoso server and imported dbpedia data into it. I found a range of SPARQL commands that don't work in isql. For example I ran this query in my isql shell.

```
SPARQL SELECT ?s  GROUP_CONCAT (?obj, ' ') as ?artist_list WHERE { ?s a dbpedia-owl:Single ;(dbpedia-owl:artist|dbpedia-owl:producer)  ?obj    } limit 10
```

It first complains about the | in (dbpedia-owl:artist|dbpedia-owl:producer), then for the GROUP_CONCAT.
I did some research into Virtuoso docs and did the following

**EDIT1**
I tried to check different cases,

**1- group_concat**

```
SPARQL select ?s (group_concat(?obj; separator='|') as ?artist_list) FROM <http://ja.dbpedia.org>  where {   ?s a dbpedia-owl:Single ;      (dbpedia-owl:artist) ?obj } group by ?s limit 10;

SQL>  syntax error at 'group_concat' before '('
```

**2- using values**

```
SPARQL select ?s  FROM <http://ja.dbpedia.org>  where {  values ?sType {dbpedia-owl:Song dbpedia-owl:Single }. ?s a ?sType} limit 10;


*** Error 37000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]SQ074: Line 1: SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 1: syntax error at 'values' before '?sType'
```

**3- using |**

```
   SPARQL select *  FROM <http://ja.dbpedia.org>  where { ?s (dbpedia-owl:artist|dbpedia-owl:producer) ?o } limit 10
    *** Error 37000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]SQ074: Line 1: SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Invalid character in SPARQL expression at '|'
```

What am I doing wrong? All above SPARQL queries work in [Standard SPARQL endpoints](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)

Comment: **"I have installed a local virtuoso server"** Some of the things you're getting parse errors about are certainly supported by some Virtuoso versions, since the DBpedia endpoint accepts them.  You need to tell us what version you installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that Virtuoso supports all of SPARQL 1.1, but your query isn't legal SPARQL either.  (Virtuoso *does* accept some stuff that's not quite SPARQL, but your query is within the realm of SPARQL.)  I suggest you take a look at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  You'll find at least the following issues:

- You didn't define the dbpedia-owl: prefix.  (You might have that in the endpoint though, so it might not be a problem.)
- It needs to be `(group_concat(…) as …)` with parenthesis.  (The case doesn't matter, though, so `GROUP_CONCAT` is fine.  I think Virtuoso will accept it without the parens, but that doesn't make it legal SPARQL.)
- In `group_concat`, you need to use a semicolon and write separator.
- If you're using aggregates like `group_concat`, then you're grouping by some variables, and you can't select a variable that you're not grouping by.  That means that you need to `group by ?s`.

Once you fix those things, you'd end up with something like:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?s (group_concat(?obj; separator=' ') as ?artist_list)
where {
  ?s a dbpedia-owl:Single ;
     (dbpedia-owl:artist|dbpedia-owl:producer) ?obj
}
group by ?s
limit 10
```

That's legal SPARQL 1.1.  If Virtuoso still complains about that, you could use a `values` block instead of the property path, and so have the following, which is equivalent:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?s (group_concat(?obj; separator=' ') as ?artist_list)
where {
  values ?p { dbpedia-owl:artist dbpedia-owl:producer }
  ?s a dbpedia-owl:Single ;
     ?p ?obj
}
group by ?s
limit 10
```

If you still get complaints about `values` (but DBpedia's endpoint supports `values`, and it's Virtuoso;  how old a version are you installing?), you can use `union`:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?s (group_concat(?obj; separator=' ') as ?artist_list)
where {
  ?s a dbpedia-owl:Single .
  { ?s dbpedia-owl:artist   ?obj } UNION
  { ?s dbpedia-owl:producer ?obj }
}
group by ?s
limit 10
```

If you want some SPARQL 1.1 support, you'll need to use at least Virtuoso 7.0.0.  The release notes include:

> #### [2013-08-05 -- Virtuoso Open-Source Edition 7.0.0 Released](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews#2013-08-05%20--%20Virtuoso%20Open-Source%20Edition%207.0.0%20Released)
>
> - Added support for SPARQL 1.1 BIND and VALUES clauses
> - Added support for SPARQL 1.1 Functions and Aggregates
> - Added support for ?graph parameter in SPARQL 1.1 Graph Protocol
> - Fixed issues with Transitivity, Inference, and SPARQL 1.1 Property Paths

Comment: It complains about values as well

Comment: (group_concat(…) as …) does not work either, prints ' syntax error at 'group_concat' before '(''

Comment: @user1848018 See updates.  That said, DBpedia's endpoint runs Virtuoso and supports `values`, so it sounds like you're installing an old version or something.

Comment: That is why I am so surprised. BTW, I edited my question and broke it down while you were doing the update. So you think it is a version problem?

Comment: **So you think it is a version problem?** I don't know.  You haven't told us what version you installed.

Comment: It is 6.1.3 so I guess you are right. I try to install the new version. Thanks again for always helping others

Comment: @user1848018 You'll want at least 7.0.0;  see the update to my answer.